# Retrieving Values from a Seq based on a condition

Tags: arrays, scala, arraylist, seq, take

I have the below Seq with me

```
scala>   var al = Seq((1.0, 20.0, 100.0), (2.0, 30.0, 100.0), (1.0, 11.0, 100.0), (1.0, 20.0, 100.0), (1.0, 10.0, 100.0),(2.0,9.0,100.0))
al: Seq[(Double, Double, Double)] = List((1.0,20.0,100.0), (2.0,30.0,100.0), (1.0,11.0,100.0), (1.0,20.0,100.0), (1.0,10.0,100.0), (2.0,9.0,100.0))
```

How to take from this Seq the first n elements where - sum of the second item is greater than 60 percent of the third item(this will be a constant value)

Expected Output -

```
scala> Seq((1.0, 20.0, 100.0), (2.0, 30.0, 100.0), (1.0, 11.0, 100.0))
res30: Seq[(Double, Double, Double)] = List((1.0,20.0,100.0), (2.0,30.0,100.0), (1.0,11.0,100.0))
```

**Edit -1**

I have done this with some ugly way. But if there is any beautiful functional way of solving this would be great. I would really need to get rid of this counters and is little bit tricky for me.

```
var counter =0d ; var sum = 0d 
var abc :Seq[Double] = for (x <- al) yield {
counter+=1 ;sum = sum + x._2 ; 
if (sum > 60) counter else 0
} 
println(al.take(abc.filterNot(_==0).min.toInt))
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: Look at the `takeWhile` method: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Seq.html it works as you need

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet , I have tried something Ugly as I am learning the functional way of solving the problem. This >>>  var counter =0d ; var sum = 0d
var abc :Seq[Double] = for (x <- al) yield {counter+=1 ;sum = sum + x._2 ;  if (sum > 60) counter else 0}
println(al.take(abc.filterNot(_==0).min.toInt))

Comment: @Boris. I was trying something which I mentioned above. But I did not correctly connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Scala 2.13.x then you might `unfold()`:

```
Seq.unfold((al,0.0)){ case (lst,sum) =>
  Option.when(lst.nonEmpty && sum < 0.6 * lst.head._3) {
    (lst.head, (lst.tail, sum + lst.head._2))
  }
}
//res0: Seq[(Double, Double, Double)] =
// List((1.0,20.0,100.0), (2.0,30.0,100.0), (1.0,11.0,100.0))
```

On earlier Scala versions you could `scanLeft()` to calculate the sums and use that to count how many elements to `take()`.

```
val cnt = al.view
            .scanLeft(0.0)(_ + _._2)
            .takeWhile(_ < 0.6 * al.headOption.getOrElse((0d,0d,0d))._3)
            .length
al.take(cnt)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursive function with accumulator to get needed number of elements:

```
def getIndex(input: Seq[(Double,Double,Double)], index: Int = 0, sum: Double = 0.0): Int = {
    input match {
    case Seq() => index
    case Seq(head, _@_*) if head._2 + sum > head._3 * 0.6 => index + 1  
    case Seq(head, tail@_*) => getIndex(tail, index + 1, sum + head._2)
  }
}

al.take(getIndex(al))
```

Or to build a list:

```
def getList(input: Seq[(Double,Double,Double)], sum: Double = 0.0): List[(Double,Double,Double)] = {
    input match {
    case Seq() => List.empty
    case Seq(head, _@_*) if head._2 + sum > head._3 * 0.6 => head :: List.empty
    case Seq(head, tail@_*) => head :: get(tail, sum + head._2)
  }
}

getList(al)
```

As mentioned in comments - restricting `al` to List can allow using `::` which should be more efficient:

```
def get(input: List[(Double,Double,Double)], sum: Double = 0.0): List[(Double,Double,Double)] = {
    input match {
    case Seq() => List.empty
    case head :: tail if head._2 + sum > head._3 * 0.6 => head :: List.empty
    case head :: tail => head :: get(tail,  sum + head._2)
  }
 }
```

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you, please check is it better now?

Comment: Yep, at least it works. It may be extremely inefficient, but yeah processing generic seas never made sense anyways. I would just ask for a **List**.

Comment: @abc_spark was glad to help!